# Using NodeJS 18 in AWS Amplify on Amazon Linux 2 fails

Tags: node.js, aws-amplify, glibc, amazon-linux

Trying to upgrade an existing React app running on AWS Amplify from node v16 to v18
The image used is the provided Amazon Linux 2

Expected it to install node 18 on the machine it spun up and build the application, since this is the LTS version

Here is the error I get in the build process:

```
2022-11-15T19:19:02.924Z [WARNING]: node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
```

Comment: The majority of these answers are now outdated,  see the correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77679955/14193416).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Linux 2 includes Glibc 2.26 or under. To use a higher glibc version, you need to consider other AMI, for example Amazon Linux 2022 (al2022-ami) as it includes glibc 2.34.

You can also revert back to Node.js 16 as it uses a lower version of Glibc.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77679955/14193416)

Answer (score 2):

The same problem happened to me, I fixed it by adding a custom image in the build config.

You can see the steps to add a custom image in the following [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/custom-build-image.html)

The image that worked for me was the following:

> public.ecr.aws/t7o4u3y2/node-18.2.0:latest

### UPDATE

Now is available support Node 18.x

Please see the update [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3773#issuecomment-1811288919)

Comment: If I change the image I get the following error: "aws codecommit credential-helper $@ get: 1: aws: not found" How did you manage to clone the repository?

Comment: What worked for me was very similar: `public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:18.14.2`. Tried pure `node:18.14.2` (straight from Docker Hub) but it was frequently failing due to pull rate limits (which the docs warn about).

Answer (score 2):

As of **April 2023**, per this [comment](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3109#:%7E:text=simply%20adding%20the-,nvm%20use%2018,-command%20to%20your):

> Node 18 available in the default Docker image for all builds! The version is pinned to 18.13.0, which you can leverage by simply adding the `nvm use 18` command to your build spec.

```yaml
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - nvm use 18
        - amplifyPush --simple
```

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for opening this issue. Amazon Linux 2 doesn't support the right GLIBC version at the moment, we're coordinating internally to get that updated. As @saharl-neosec mentions, you can provide a custom docker image until we fully support it:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3109

Answer (score 0):

To build Custom images (nodejs) for AWS Amplify follow this pattern.

```
public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:your_node_version
```

For example if you want to use Node.js version `v18.16.0`

```
public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:18.16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched to "Amazon Linux:2023" which is the default as of this writing and it fixed my issue.

I then didn't have to have any other setting to get Node 18.