# Issue with Amplify custom build image

Tags: node.js, aws-amplify

I have a website with node.js 18.12.1 and gatsby.js v5. Last week, Amplify threw me this error: BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7WZ5.png)

[My custom build image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKc8F.png)

I need to especify mi node version.

If i change my build settings to Amazon linux 2 the project does not compile

[New custom build image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mynUZ.png)

[error to compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFWHF.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74768737/using-nodejs-18-in-aws-amplify-on-amazon-linux-2-fails

Comment: Thank you so much!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74870584/19524685
I have managed to solve my problem using this docker image:
public.ecr.aws/t7o4u3y2/node-18.2.0:latest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you so much!
[Using NodeJS 18 in AWS Amplify on Amazon Linux 2 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74768737/using-nodejs-18-in-aws-amplify-on-amazon-linux-2-fails/74870584#74870584)
I have managed to solve my problem using this docker image: public.ecr.aws/t7o4u3y2/node-18.2.0:latest

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.