# Astro v 3 require Node js 18 and AWS amplify fail to build due to version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)

Tags: aws-amplify, astrojs

I have Astro v3 and trying to build using AWS amplify but it does not build and fail with below detail, updated build setting to node js v 18.14.1 but when build it gives error

```
# Starting phase: preBuild
2023-10-07T18:15:08.707Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm ci
2023-10-07T18:15:08.708Z [WARNING]: node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
                                    node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
2023-10-07T18:15:08.709Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-10-07T18:15:08.709Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-10-07T18:15:08.709Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-10-07T18:15:08.709Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

someone can help me how it can be solved. AWS amplify use build image Amazon Linux 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using NodeJS 18 in AWS Amplify on Amazon Linux 2 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74768737/using-nodejs-18-in-aws-amplify-on-amazon-linux-2-fails)

Comment: using that link; i am able to update node js version but not the build image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Amazon Linux:2023 Image and for my live package updates I added a Node.js one and set it to 18.14.1.

This worked and has been my first time successfully hosting an astro site with this recent issue.

Comment: It works. Even with astro 4

Comment: Do we need to setup and redirect and rewrite rule for astro with custom domain?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue - a solution was to use a custom build image like `public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:18.14.1` (18.14.1 being the minimum supported version by Astro) in your build image settings.

Some other solutions like `nvm install <version>` didn't change anything.